# Prevent multiple asynchronous calls from being in flight simultaneously without blocking

Tags: java, design-patterns, concurrency

Here's essentially my problem:

```
while (true) {
  if (previous 'doWorkAsync' method is not still in flight) {
    doWorkAsync()  // this returns immediately
  }
  wait set amount of time
}
```

A couple solutions come to mind for me:

1. Block until doWorkAsync() completes. This is not desirable to me for a few reasons.
   It (potentially) results in waiting longer than I really needed to in the 'wait some set amount of time' line (e.g. if doWorkAsync takes 5 seconds, and the set amount of waiting time is 10 seconds, this will result in 15 seconds of waiting between calls, which isn't what I wanted). Of course, I could account for this by waiting less time, but somehow it just feels clunky.
   It also ties up this thread unnecessarily. Instead of waiting for this task to come back, this thread could handle other work, like making config updates so the next call to doWorkAsync() has fresh data.
2. Use a gating mechanism. The easiest implementation that comes to mind is a boolean, set  before calls to doWorkAsync(), and unset when doWorkAsync() completes. This is essentially what I'm doing now, but I'm not sure if it's an anti-pattern??

Is #2 the right way to go, or are there better ways to solve this problem?

**EDIT**: If it helps, doWorkAsync() returns a ListenableFuture (of guava).

The original question may not have been 100% clear. Here's the crux. If the async request finishes before the given timeout, this code will always work. However, if the async task takes SET_AMOUNT_OF_TIME + epsilon to complete, then this code will sleep twice as long as necessary, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: What's wrong with joining the thread of the async work with zero time out

Comment: @EliAlgranti I don't want to block. Thread.join() will block until the async task completes.

Comment: You are in an infinite loop, sleeping.  How can blocking be a problem?

Comment: @user949300, Yes, I think I realized this after thinking a bit more. I think my solutions below solves this. Let me know what you think.

Comment: @knighty Thread.join(0) does not block http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join(long)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is using the `wait` and `notifyAll` methods already in Java. All you need to do is use an `AtomicBoolean` as a flag and block on it until the another `Thread` tells you something has changed.

The difference between that and your approach is that a blocked thread doesn't do anything whereas a polling thread uses CPU time.

Here is a simple example using two `Thread`s - the `Runnable` "`First`" is submitted and it waits on `done` until the `Runnable` "`Second`" notifies that it has changed the flag.

```
public class App {

    private static final AtomicBoolean done = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    private static final class First implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!done.get()) {
                System.out.println("Waiting.");
                synchronized (done) {
                    try {
                        done.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Done!");
        }
    }

    private static final class Second implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                return;
            }
            done.set(true);
            synchronized (done) {
                done.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        executorService.submit(new First());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        executorService.submit(new Second());
        executorService.shutdown();

    }
}
```

The `sleep` calls are just to show that a task of arbitrary  length can take place, obviously they are not required.

The thing to note is that `First` prints "waiting" *every time* it enters the loop and, if you run the code, it only prints it once. The second thing to note is that `First` reacts to the changing of the flag immediately as it is told to awake and recheck when the flag is changed.

I have used `return` in the `InterruptedException` blocks, you may want to used `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` instead so that the process doesn't die if it's spuriously interrupted.

A more advanced approach is to use `Lock` and `Condition`

```
public class App {

    private static final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private static final Condition condition = lock.newCondition();

    private static final class First implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            lock.lock();
            System.out.println("Waiting");
            try {
                condition.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                return;
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
            System.out.println("Done!");
        }
    }

    private static final class Second implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                condition.signalAll();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                return;
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        executorService.submit(new First());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        executorService.submit(new Second());
        executorService.shutdown();

    }
}
```

In this situation `First` acquires a lock on the `Lock` object the immediately calls `await` on the `Condition`. The releases the lock and blocks on the `Condition`.

`Second` then acquires a lock on the `Lock` and calls `signalAll` on the `Condition` which awakes `First`.

`First` then reacquires the lock and continues execution, printing "Done!".

**EDIT**

The OP would like to call the method `doWorkAsync` with a specified period, if the method takes less time than the period then the process has to wait. If the method takes longer then the method should be called again immediately after.

The task needs to be stopped after a certain time.

At no point should the method be running more than once simultaneously.

The easiest approach would be to call the method from a `ScheduledExecutorService`, the `Runnable` would wrap the method and call `get` on the `Future` - blocking the scheduled executor until it is done.

This guarantees that the method is called with *at least* `WAIT_TIME_BETWEEN_CALLS_SECS` delay.

Then schedule another task that kills the first one after a set time.

```
final ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
final Future<?> taskHandle = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final ListenableFuture<Void> lf = doWorkAsync();
        try {
            doWorkAsync().get();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}, 0, WAIT_TIME_BETWEEN_CALLS_SECS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
scheduledExecutorService.schedule(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        taskHandle.cancel(false);
    }
}, TOTAL_TIME_SECS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The best solution would be call the raw `Runnable` on a `ScheduledExecutorService` rather than calling it on another executor and blocking on the `ListenableFuture`.

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of either of these approaches, as they require the asynchronous task to be aware of the caller (they both use the globally available flag). I prefer an approach where the caller does all the logic, and the asynchronous task happily starts the asynchronous task and returns a listenable furue.

Comment: You can always wrap your previous `doWorkAsync` method in a `WaitingRunnable` or some such so that the blocking is done there. The flag doesn't have to be global it can be passed into the `Runnables`. Your proposed solution, as far as I can see, still uses `Thread.sleep` - this is **always** a bad idea and is indicative of code smell. This solution does not sleep of arbitrary lengths of time but blocks until _the instant_ that the task completes.

Comment: How can I make sure that I wait at least the requisite amount of time though, without a sleep? The async task may finish much faster than the amount of time before I'm allowed to call the function again.

Comment: You seem to be reinventing a `ScheduledExecutorService` - why not use that?

Comment: That was my first thought, but it doesn't meet the full criteria. If the async task takes longer than time to wait before launching the next one (which I want to allow), then the task will get scheduled and I'll have two in flight at once.

Comment: No. You will not. First, you can block in the executor thread and wait for the async task to complete - if the executor is single threaded you **can not** have more than one task in progress. Second with the [`scheduleAtFixedRate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) method you can have it so that a task will execute _at least_ delay seconds after the previous one.

Comment: The delay you provide to that method is only initial delay, but does not affect future delays once the first task has begun. Either way, that would still not help me, as I need to make sure not call doWorkAsync() again if it's currently happening, no matter the delay.

Comment: The last answer is perfect. I didn't notice before this line from ScheduledExecutorService:

"If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute."

Comment: I missed that one too when I first started fiddling with Executors.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me while sorting out this question! I don't know how to repay you other than accepting your answer, so hopefully that's sufficient :)

Comment: Some of us enjoy messing around with code - I think that's why this site works. Glad I could help!

Comment: If I may, still struggling a bit with the next step here. The ScheduledExecutor returns a ScheduledFuture. Now I want to say, let this scheduledExecutorService run for TOTAL_TIME_SECS, then stop it and end the program. What's the cleanest way to do that while working only with a scheduled future?

Comment: @knightry I have edited by answer. NB, this approach is described in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html).

Answer (score 0):

Think what you are looking for is [The Reactor Pattern](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/PDF/reactor-siemens.pdf).

Is there a reason you don't want these things running at the same time? If what you want to do is chain them, you could use Futures. [Akka](http://akka.io) has Composable Futures and mappable ones.

Comment: The Reactor Pattern looks different than what I'm after. I only have one future getting return that I need to gate on, not multiple inputs to react to.

Also, not sure I understand your question. Which 'things' are you referring to? Can you elaborate on how I could use Futures to get the desired behavior of waiting the set amount of time?

Comment: I brought up Reactor because I thought you were trying to keep the threads from running into each other. Or that you were trying to chain, that's why I said either or. Futures are chained and what happens is, when the first one completes, the second one is kicked off, and there are no sleeps or waits.

Comment: Yeah, I understand how Futures.transform() works. The problem is, my service is rate-limited with how much it can call doWorkAsync(), so I don't want to call it again just as soon as it comes back. Otherwise, I wouldn't have the problem in the first place :)

Comment: Yeah this question was not clear at all. I see kind of what you are trying to do now, but not why. Are you attempting to make sure you don't exceed some number of requests per hour or day? If that's the case, you should model that, and perhaps schedule the requests all at once to trigger at intervals? Then who cares whether it's too soon to call?? So if you are allowed one an hour, loop through scheduling first for now, second hour from now, so on.. ?

Comment: Yes, attempting to make sure I don't make too many requests in a given time frame (this code will always run for a set amount of time then terminate, and I need to make sure in the time it's running it doesn't call that function more than X times, bascially).

And that's exactly what I ended up doing, by using a ScheduledExecutorService.